# how to fill other part of a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have in cells A1 19,200, B1 13/05/2020 and cells C1 72. When i execute the VBA a table is created in Word as per below and it continues to 72

```
Instal No   Amt(Rs) Due Date    Instal No   Amt(Rs) Due Date
1   19200   13/05/2020          
2   19200   13/06/2020          
3   19200   13/07/2020          
4   19200   13/08/2020          
5   19200   13/09/2020          
6   19200   13/10/2020          
7   19200   13/11/2020          
8   19200   13/12/2020          
9   19200   13/01/2021          
10  19200   13/02/2021          
11  19200   13/03/2021          
12  19200   13/04/2021          
13  19200   13/05/2021          
14  19200   13/06/2021          
15  19200   13/07/2021          
16  19200   13/08/2021
```

Please note that C1 is the number of months(i,e Instal No).

What i want to achieve is to fill  the other part to the right of the blank of the table.Let me clarify if C1= 72 months then split it half that is send 36 months to the other side of the table.My number of months are even numbers(24,36,48,60,98)

You will notice that i have added 1 to "lngRows = Range("C1").Value + 1" because of the headings

my codes are as follows :-

```
Sub CreateTableInWord()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objTbl As Object
Dim objRow As Object
Dim objCol As Object
Dim lngCols As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim I As Long

    lngCols = 6
    lngRows = 72

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=0)

    Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, NumRows:=lngRows, NumColumns:=lngCols)

    Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(1)


   objTbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Instal No"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Due Date"
   objTbl.Cell(2, 3) = Range("B1").Value
   objTbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Instal No"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 4).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 5).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "Due Date"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 6).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    For I = 2 To lngRows

    ' For j = 1 To intNoOfColumns

  objTbl.Cell(I, 1).Range = I - 1

     Next

   For S = 2 To lngRows

  objTbl.Cell(S, 2) = Range("A1").Value

    Next

For T = 2 To lngRows

objTbl.Cell(T, 3).Range.Text = Format(DateAdd("m", T - 2, Range("B1").Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Next T




    Set objCol = Nothing

    Set objRow = Nothing

    Set objDoc = Nothing

    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Fill by column or fill by row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Sub CreateTableInWord()

    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, objTbl As Object, objRow As Object
    Dim objCol As Object, colSets As Long, numMonths As Long, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long
    Dim amt, dtStart, tblRows As Long, tblCols As Long, rw As Long, col As Long

    numMonths = Range("A1").Value
    amt = Range("B1").Value
    dtStart = Range("C1").Value
    colSets = Range("D1").Value 'how many sets of columns ?

    tblRows = 1 + Application.Ceiling(numMonths / colSets, 1) 'how many table rows?
    tblCols = colSets * 3                                     'how many table cols?

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=0)
    Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, _
                 NumRows:=tblRows, NumColumns:=tblCols)

    c = 0
    For n = 1 To colSets
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Text = "Instal No"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 2).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 2).Range.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 3).Range.Text = "Due Date"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 3).Range.Bold = True
        c = c + 3
    Next n
    objTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1 ' wdAlignParagraphCenter

    rw = 2
    col = 0
    For i = 1 To numMonths

        'rw = 1 + Application.Ceiling(i / colSets, 1)  'fill across and then down
        rw = IIf(i Mod (tblRows - 1) = 1, 2, rw + 1)   'fill down then across

        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 1).Range.Text = i
        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 2).Range.Text = amt
        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 3).Range.Text = DateAdd("m", i - 1, dtStart)

        'col = IIf(i Mod colSets = 0, 0, col + 3)         'fill across and then down
        col = IIf(i Mod (tblRows - 1) = 0, col + 3, col) 'fill down and then across

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: will check it and revert to u .Thanks